# Windows 7: Install Type 1 fonts via command line

Tags: windows-7, automated-install, font

So I have a number of Type 1 fonts (.PFM & .PFB files) that I am trying to push out to our client machines. After some web searches, here is what I did.

1. On my machine, I installed all of the fonts by opening the font file in windows explorer and clicked the "Install" button.
2. Exported the following registry location: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Type 1 Installer\Type 1 Fonts`
3. Created a batch file that would copy the files and import the registry information.
4. Ran batch file "as Administrator" on a machine with UAC turned on.
5. Restarted computer and checked for font install.

So far, no luck on the fonts. I have to have a "silent installer" for these fonts so I can push it out to the 100+ machines this needs to go on.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a bit of work I have fount that the best way to do this is to convert the fonts to open type fonts. Then you can deploy the font to the machine. Here is where I converted my fonts:

http://onlinefontconverter.com/

Once converted to ".otf", you can do the following steps:

1. Copy Font files to C:\Windows\Fonts
2. Modify the proper registry entry:

   "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts"

There are a number of other fonts already installed so you can just mirror the registry settings of another font.